# Computing the distance between two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, numerical-methods

Consider the set $x = \{(a, y) | 0<=a<=b | a,b,y \in Z\}$.

Now for example lets say $a=0$, $b=5$, $y=0$. Then x = $\{(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3,0), (4,0)\}$

I know since $|x| = 5$ that what we will call the best distribution is
$s = \{(0,0), (2,0), (4,0)\}$

Now consider a set $c = \{(0,0), (3,0), (4,0)\} \subset x $.

What is the best way to represent how "close" or "far away" $c$ is to $s$? Note that in this simple example $|c| = |s|$ but in the abstract case where $c \subset x$ this is not always true. Should I approach this using euclidean distance or is there some specific statistical analysis that would work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not at all obvious what you mean by the best distribution, nor what distance you want to use.  One obvious distance would be $d=|c \setminus s|$.  It fulfills all the requirements of a metric: symmetry, positive unless the two arguments match, and the triangle inequality.